# AppleScript for Outlook - Move Unread Older Than X

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I'm looking for an AppleScript that can be used to delete all unread messages older than 90 days within a specific one of my inboxes. I've searched extensively and have not been able to find any information related to this particular search.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for an AppleScript, but if you are willing to consider another approach, this can be easily accomplished by using an Outlook Rule.  This will have the advantage of always being in place, whereas with the AppleScript you will need to schedule it or run it periodically.

[image]